# How can I set the belongs_to association of a new object via a dropdown menu in the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, model-associations

So I'm new to Rails, and I've just finished going through Michael's Hartl's railstutorial.org.
I'm now building my first app, and i'm encountering my first road block.

So basically i've got Bubbles (which are equivalent to subjects) and Rumors.
Rumors belongs_to bubbles, and Bubbles have many Rumors.
When creating a new rumor, the user must select the Bubble it belongs to.

I've created my 2 models as follow:

```
class Bubble < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name

  has_many :rumors, dependent: destroy

  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 300 }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

and

```
class Rumor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :bubble_id

  belongs_to :bubble

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 300 }
  validates :bubble_id, presence: true
end
```

The form to create a new Rumor is rendered on the home page:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@rumor) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :content %>
    <%= f.input :bubble_id, collection: @bubbles %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Therefore I've defined the variables in my StaticPagesController:

```
def home
  @bubbles = Bubble.all
  @rumor = Rumor.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @bubble }
  end
end
```

My Bubble controller is as follows:
class BubblesController < ApplicationController

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :edit, :destroy]

  # GET /bubbles
  # GET /bubbles.json
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @bubbles = Bubble.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @bubbles = Bubble.all
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bubbles }
    end
  end

  # GET /bubbles/1
  # GET /bubbles/1.json
  def show
    @bubble = Bubble.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bubble }
    end
  end

  # GET /bubbles/new
  # GET /bubbles/new.json
  def new
    @bubble = Bubble.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bubble }
    end
  end

  # GET /bubbles/1/edit
  def edit
    @bubble = Bubble.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /bubbles
  # POST /bubbles.json
  def create
    @bubble = Bubble.new(params[:bubble])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bubble.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bubble, notice: 'Bubble was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @bubble, status: :created, location: @bubble }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @bubble.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /bubbles/1
  # PUT /bubbles/1.json
  def update
    @bubble = Bubble.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bubble.update_attributes(params[:bubble])
        format.html { redirect_to @bubble, notice: 'Bubble was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @bubble.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /bubbles/1
  # DELETE /bubbles/1.json
  def destroy
    @bubble = Bubble.find(params[:id])
    @bubble.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bubbles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

And the Rumors controller:

```
class RumorsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]

  # GET /rumors
  # GET /rumors.json
  def index
    @rumors = Rumor.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @rumors }
    end
  end

  # GET /rumors/1
  # GET /rumors/1.json
  def show
    @rumor = Rumor.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @rumor }
    end
  end

  # GET /rumors/new
  # GET /rumors/new.json
  def new
    @rumor = Rumor.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @rumor }
    end
  end

  # GET /rumors/1/edit
  def edit
    @rumor = Rumor.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /rumors
  # POST /rumors.json
  def create
    @rumor = Rumor.new(params[:rumor])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rumor.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rumor, notice: 'Rumor was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @rumor, status: :created, location: @rumor }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @rumor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /rumors/1
  # PUT /rumors/1.json
  def update
    @rumor = Rumor.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rumor.update_attributes(params[:rumor])
        format.html { redirect_to @rumor, notice: 'Rumor was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @rumor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /rumors/1
  # DELETE /rumors/1.json
  def destroy
    @rumor = Rumor.find(params[:id])
    @rumor.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to rumors_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm still having quite a hard time figuring out how to build an association through a form, so any help is appreciated, even if it's not the full solution to my problem.

Comment: Do those errors give you a stack trace? What lines of code are they coming from, etc.

Comment: I've edited the question to add the full trace. Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Comment: You need another action that will be used as target for the form's POST request. You can't create a new Rumor with just one action. That's why the default in Rails is to use the `new` and `create` actions. If you want to use different actions that's fine, but you need to specify the URL in the `simple_form_for` tag.

Comment: How and where should I implement this action?

Comment: You would implement the action in a `RumorsController`. I'm a bit perplexed about some things: Why would you have a Rumor accept nested attributes for its parent (Bubble)? Why do you call the BubblesController to create Rumors? Please post you routes.rb, your RumorsController and perhaps your BubblesController as well.

Comment: The nested_attribute line was a reminiscence from a tutorial I'd followed. I removed it as it did not have its place here. I've edited the question to include both controllers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I figured out a solution following the Railscast about tags. It's probably not the cleanest way to do it, but it works. You can take a look at my repo over here if you'd like: https://github.com/mikaeltheimer/rumr